# Insufficient Permission creating gmail group using Google Directory API

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-directory-api

I want to create group which contains some email/gmails. I am using this [guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python). This is my code for creating groups:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group'
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid {
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
}
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

mdig = createetag();

reqbody = {
    "kind": "admin#directory#group",
    "id": "id065468",
    "etag": "%s" % mdig,
    "email": "grpatest065469@gmail.com",
    "name": "Grptest name",
    "directMembersCount": "2",
    "description": "Grptest",
    "adminCreated": "True",
    "aliases": [
        "first@gmail.com",
        "second@gmail.com"
    ],
    "nonEditableAliases": [
    ]
}

# Call the Admin SDK Directory API
print('Creating new group')
group = service.groups()
g = group.insert(body=reqbody).execute()
```

I didn't get authentication window in my browser, not sure if that's causing the problem. This is my error:

```
'kind': 'admin#directory#group', 'id': 'id065468', 'etag': "b'\\x9fR\\xe9O\\x93\\x84\\xbe~\\x19\\xef\\xd2DYJ`\\x1d'", 'email': 'grptest065469@gmail.com', 'name': 'Grptest name', 'directMembersCount': '2', 'description': 'Grp test', 'adminCreated': 'True', 'aliases': ['first@gmail.com', 'second@gmail.com'],'nonEditableAliases': []

Creating new group

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\creategrp.py", line 105, in <module> main()
File".\creategrp.py", line 75, in main 
    g = group.insert(body=reqbody).execute()
File "C:\dev\cfehome\lib\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\dev\cfehome\lib\googleapiclient\http.py", line 849, in execute 
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Groups: insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/insert) requires `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group` scope in order to use it.   On top of that the user who you have authenticated with must have access to do what it is you are trying to do.  Your code appears to use the correct scope.

> "Insufficient Permission"

Can mean one of two things.  Either

- the user you are authenticating does not have access to do what you are trying to do
- you have changed the scope since the user logged in.

option one:

Make sure that the user you are logging in with has admin access on the gsuite account.  or you may want to check out service accounts below.

Option two:

I am not a python developer but i know about about the library you are using.  When the user logs in a credential file for the user in a directory denoted by `stored store = file.Storage('token.json')`.  By doing this when the user comes back again you dont have to ask them to log in again.  If you have changed the scope what you need to do is go find that file and delete it.  It should pop up and ask you for consent again.

**Service Account**

In the event that you wish to run this server sided you can use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and set up [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation) this way when the script runs the service account will be able to apply these changes as needed.  However seeing as you appear to be just creating a group you may not need to go though the trouble of creating a service account and setting it up if the user you are logging in with has the access anyway.

Google Api Python client documentation -> [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts)

Comment: I think it's option 1: the user that Im authenticating doesn't have access. Do you know how to give user access to gsuite. Does it have to do with enabling Admin SDK api in user's dashboard?

Comment: I am not sure i would think it more has to do with what level access that user has in Gsuite

Comment: `Admin SDK lets administrators of enterprise domains to view and manage resources like user, groups etc. It also provides audit and usage reports of domain.`  
I found this about Admin SDK. I enabled it, deleted token.json, tried to outh again, but it says 'Insufficient Permission'.

Comment: `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: returned "Domain not found.">` Ok, I got this error now.

Comment: I tried to send from my gmail to two others email, but it says domain not found..

Comment: Don't know why I get this, created new creditentials and token files with correct SCOPE.

Answer (score 2):

The credentials that you are using do not have permission. This is caused by one or more factors related to G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation and / or Service Account credentials impersonation (the lack of).

1. You need to create a Service Account. Do not modify or change any permissions.
2. You need to delegate Domain-Wide Authority to the Service Account.
3. Using the Service Account credentials you impersonate another User that has domain superadmin privilege and who has logged in at least once into G Suite and accepted the terms and conditions.

Start with this document on G Suite Domain Delegation:

[Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation)